# Python 3.X Selenium autologin fail

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to make a autologin by myself. Here is my code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://omega-pentest.borec.cz/')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

idElem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "prom1")))
idElem.send_keys('cyka')
idElem.click()


pwElem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "prom2")))
pwElem.send_keys('bliat')
pwElem.click()
```

I keep getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Duchy\Desktop\web.py", line 11, in 
>       idElem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "prom1")))   File
>   "C:\Users\Duchy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py",
>   line 80, in until
>       raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: I think the problem is from your network , it doesn't respond in time so it raises a Timeout Exception

Comment: it waits 10 seconds before executing-> the page is fully loaded.

Comment: By the way I'm not russian , but cyka bliat is very familiar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two elements `prom1` and `prom2` are not `By.ID()`, but `By.Name()`. You can see from the source, there is no `id` attribute:

```
<input name="prom1" required="" type="text">
<input name="prom2" required="" type="password">
```

Also, the two `.click()` statements are completely unnecessary and can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

First off I love the Russian Curseword here :D
To fix this issue try using the XPATH instead of the ID something like this:

```py
import selenium
import shutil
import xlsxwriter
import os
import unittest
import requests
import subprocess
import getpass
import platform
import socket
import ssl
import pynput
import logging
import time 
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from datetime import date

import json
with open('secrets.json','r') as f:
      config = json.load(f)

# WebDriver Path for OS.System
if platform.system() == ('Windows'):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")
elif platform.system() == ('Linux'):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/rbarrett/Drivers/Google/Chrome/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver')
elif platform.system() == ('Darwin'):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='~/Drivers/Google/Chrome/chromedriver_mac64/chromedriver')
else:
    print("Are you sure you have the Selenium Webdriver installed in the correct path?")

# TearDown Method
def tearDown(self):
    self.browser.close()

# ShutDown Method 
def shutDown(self):
    self.browser.quit()

# Parent URL
#browser.get(config['URL']['target_url'])

# Credentials NEEDS UNIT TEST
username = browser.find_element_by_id("login")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("password")
username.send_keys(config['user']['name'])
password.send_keys(config['user']['password'])

# Authentication submit.click()
# For XPATH = //*[@id='bLogin']
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='bLogin']")))
element.click();
print("Logging into <insert_program>!")
print("Authenticated")
```

I use other imports there for my own coding issues, but you can find some examples on here if you want: https://github.com/Richard-Barrett/ITDataServicesInfra/tree/master/Python